# How to return a null json_encode object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I basically have an ajax function which gets the latest posts from a database, what I want to know is if no data is found what should I return seeing as returning null seems to be an issue for firebug?

**php code**

```
function getLatestChat(){
   global $session, $form;

   $data = $session->getLatestChat(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['withUser']),
      mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['ignoreMessages']));

   if($data){//successful
      echo json_encode($data);   
   }        

   return;
}
```

**jquery code**

```
function getLatestChat(){
   var ignoreMessagesArr = $(".chatID").map(function(){ return this.value;}).get().join(",");

   $.ajax({
      traditional: true,
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET", url: "include/process.php", 
      data:{
      getLatestChat: "true",
         withUser: currentCCID,
     ignoreMessages: ignoreMessagesArr
      },
      success: function(data){
         $.each(data, function(i, elem){
        $('.chat-latestContainer').append(elem.value);
     });             
      }
   }
});
```

at the moment the method either returns the **$data** object or **null**.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the Javascript code the causes the error (The handler for the Ajax response)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return an empty object to represent no data in the object:

```
return '{}';
```

Or if your Javascript code expects an array, return an empty array:

```
return '[]';
```

Comment: that does not fix the problem, I still get object is null

Comment: @mk_89 Then you need to fix your Javascript, not your server side code.

Comment: your right in my jquery code I have should check whether the object is null

Comment: @mk_89 Okay, so were you able to fix it yourself, or do you want help with your Javascript?

Comment: yeh i fixed the jquery part with JQuery.isArray() I was just unsure about the correct way to return a null json_encode object in php. thanks

Comment: why not just return an empty array ? `jQuery.each` can handle empty collections :)

Answer (score 1):

Run a simple

```
if(isset($retunValue)){
 //code
}
```

check on it to check to see if its set.

you can also try a

```
if(!empty($returnValue)){
  //code
}
```

in your if code you can set it to whatever fits your needs for further use. If it's unneeded you can disregard it and just pass your function something back that wont throw an error.

Comment: `isset()` is not the same as `!empty()`.

Comment: im returning a json_encode array, meaning its meant for jquery so this code would not apply

Comment: @mk_89 if your using jquery .ajax() function you can set your success function code to execute this check. Or are you getting errors before the success function?

Comment: no the success function works fine, and the data goes through fine, im guessing in my success function I should check if the object is not null?

Comment: @mk_89 found a post on the jquery forum that might help [check it out](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/if-isset-equivalent-for-jquery)

Comment: @mk_89 yes I would just check if is it not null and then continue with the rest of your code. If it is null you can disregard it or do whatever needs to be done.

Comment: @mk_89 The link might be overkill. Try to just check if it's null first.

Comment: OK i will try that, i'll just need to remember how to do so in jquery

Comment: ok i've kind of fixed the issue, i've used the JQuery.isArray() function to check if the data is an array, thanks for all your typing

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite as (for example):

```
function getLatestChat($session, $form){
   $ret = {};

   $data = $session->getLatestChat(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['withUser']),
      mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['ignoreMessages']));

   if($data){//successful
      $ret = json_encode($data);   
   }        

   return $ret;
}

echo getLatestChat($session, $form);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I'm inclined to explicitly state th response type, but maybe there are more established practices...

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

// ... do stuff here: fetch data, json_encode etc.

// No data, no response
if (strlen($json) === 0) { // assuming we json encoded the data above
    header('HTTP/1.1 204 No Content');        
    exit();
}

// everything is ok
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
echo $json;
```

I just checked this on FF11 and the latest Firebug, and it seems to work okay.